# How to integrate this sum to ArrayFormula?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, cumulative-sum

I would like the cell to always sum all cells that are superior. When I drag, the formula is copied correctly:

```
**CelJ3** =SE(I3="";"";SUM($I$2:I3))
**CelJ4** =SE(I4="";"";SUM($I$2:I4))
.
.
.
.
**CelJ100** =SE(I100="";"";SUM($I$2:I100))
```

But how do you put this formula in the ArrayFormula so that every column contains the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete everything you have in J column and use this in J3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(I3:I="",,SUMIF(ROW(I3:I), "<="&ROW(I3:I), I3:I)))
```

[image]

---

### faster formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(
 TRANSPOSE((ROW(INDIRECT("I3:I"&MAX(ROW(I:I)*(I:I<>""))))<=
 TRANSPOSE( ROW(INDIRECT("I3:I"&MAX(ROW(I:I)*(I:I<>""))))))*
                INDIRECT("I3:I"&MAX(ROW(I:I)*(I:I<>"")))),
          QUERY(INDIRECT("I3:I"&MAX(ROW(I:I)*(I:I<>""))),  
          "select 1 label 1''")))
```

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, at first it worked, but the result is unfeasible, it returns the value correctly, but when I add a new data, it takes several minutes to provide the result

Comment: @ChrisPattersonFernandes can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @ChrisPattersonFernandes answer updated...

Comment: thanks again, the quick formula was perfect